# Why doesn't Leia get Force training in the original movies?

Tags: star-wars, jedi-training

Wouldn't taking down the Empire have been easier with two Jedi? I'm looking for in-universe reasons and storytelling explanations.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  For instance, why didn't Leia go with Luke to Dagobah to train under Yoda?

Comment: No. I want broad responses to why she was a worse choice for training than Luke or why Lucas decided she shouldn't be trained in the movies. The question is broad, not vague to the point of being unmanageable.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because Luke is a Mary-Sue character for Lucas. He was even called Lucas Starkiller in the earliest scripts.

Comment: There is speculation that the big reveal that they were separated twins was only conceived of after the first movie. This abbreviates the plot opportunities for it to happen, and interferes with any such development.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest explanation is that Leia was more valuable in her role as a diplomat for the rebellion.  Being a Jedi was basically a death sentence after Order 66 and Kenobi either didn't want to risk both children of Anakin at the same time by exposing them as Jedi or didn't find it feasible.

It's strategically sound. Less risk, more reward. Leia has been very active in the rebellion by the time Luke picks up his first lightsaber.  And if something happens to luke, Kenobi and Yoda seem confident they can try to train Leia in the force if they need.

Comment: That assumes that Kenobi has already decided to bet on Luke, which I take issue with. Wouldn't a diplomat and a Jedi have been more useful? Why didn't he train Leia first and use Luke as the back-up?

Comment: Because he can't be in two places at once.  Kenobi agreed to look after Luke.  Leia went with Bail Organa.

Also, Leia shows nearly zero force talent leading up to the movies, little during the movies, and almost disdain for it in the EU.  Luke, on the other hand, is a Jedi Knight in a matter of parsecs.

Comment: It still feels incredibly irresponsible to not equip the twin that is in danger and being actively pursued by Darth Vader. If he had managed to take a year off or something just to train Leia in the basics and lightsaber combat, maybe she wouldn't have needed to be rescued by a backwater kid who was trained on the fly. Also, the parsecs reference is a pun, right? You know its a measure of distance and not time.

Comment: Yes, apologies for bad Han Solo humor.  And I don't think you can just give someone a crash course in being a Jedi for a year while the Empire is still actively trying to kill off all the Jedi and any potential Jedi.  If they had wanted to train Leia, she should have been on Dagobah like Luke was on Tatooine.  But then, no diplomat. You just have two backwater kids instead of one.

Comment: Fair point. I'm still unsatisfied as to the exact strength of the Empire's Jedi detection, as Leia is constantly in populated areas and she never gets made as Force-sensitive, but I'll chalk it up to bad writing. They better swap which gender gets to be diplomats and which gender gets to be Jedi the next time around though. Getting pretty indefensible.

Comment: In the book canon, her powers are substantially less than his, even with extensive training

Comment: If it's empowered female characters you are looking for - you'll probably want to wander away from the movies.  Lucas does not handle female characters well, imho.  He makes up a little bit for having a hand in Ahsoka - but the novels (and even games) have a better, broader range of women.  Even Leia is less of your typical movie character in the later books.

Comment: Known. Won't stop me from hoping for better female characters in the new trilogy, or even *gasp* them being focused around a woman's hero/villain's journey instead of a boy's.